# Proof by induction for indices

Tags: real-analysis, induction

Let $(x_{n_{k}})$ be a subsequence of $(x_n)$. Prove rigorously by induction that the indices of the subsequence satisfy $n_{k}\geq k$.

Im not sure how to start this problem (other than the obvious starting with a base case then doing the inductive step). Im not sure what exactly the question is asking. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of  a subsequence $n_1 <n_2<...$. Use a simple induction argument to show that $n_k \geq k$ for all $k$.

Comment: Can you elaborate just a little more? What would be my base case?

Comment: $n_1 \geq 1$ because $n_1$ is a positive integer. If $n_k \geq k$  then $n_{k+1} \geq k+1$ because $n_{k+1} >n_k$. @Rivas

Comment: Your second sentence is that still part of the base case or is that the inductive step?

Comment: Also how do we know that $n_{1}$ is a positive integer?

Comment: @Rivas Look for defintion of a subsequence to find out why $n_1$ is a positive integer.The second sentence in my comment is the inductive step.

Comment: Can I write (Base Case): Let k=1, then since $n_1$ is a positive integer, we have $n_1 \geq 1$.